# Props changes arenot reflected on component UI although the new state is shown in console in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to do some react/redux basics here, but have the problem that the change in state inside the state store isn't reflected in component UI. here is my code, what wrong did I made?

projectReducer.js

Here is the reducer:

```
const initState = {
    projects: [],
};

const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_PROJECT:
            const project = action.project;
            state.projects.unshift(project);
            return {
                ...state
            };
        case GET_PROJECTS:
            state.projects = action.projects;
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default projectReducer
```

projectAction.js

Here is the action

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const createProjectActionCreator = project => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // make async call to dispatch 
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/projects/create-project', project).then(result => {
           dispatch({
                type: 'CREATE_PROJECT',
                project: result.data.project
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
} 

export const getProjectsActionsCreator = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/projects").then(result => {
           dispatch({
                type: 'GET_PROJECTS',
                projects: result.data.projects
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    };
}
```

createProjectComponent.js

Here is compnent has create project form

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createProjectActionCreator } from "../../store/actions/projectActions";

class CreateProject extends React.Component {

    state = {
        projectData: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        },
        createProjectErrors: []
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        const { id, value } = e.target;
        const { projectData }  = this.state;
        projectData[id] = value;
        this.setState({projectData});
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.createProject(this.state.projectData);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)} className="white">
                    <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create New Project</h5>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="title" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
                        <textarea className="materialize-textarea" id="content" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create Project</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        createProject: project => dispatch(createProjectActionCreator(project))
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject)
```

Dashboard.js

This component act like home page which renders project list and the form of project creation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Notifications from './Notifications';
import ProjectList from '../projects/PorjectList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CreateProject from '../projects/CreateProject';
import { getProjectsActionsCreator } from "../../store/actions/projectActions";

class Dashoard extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
       this.props.fetchProjects();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="dashboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <ProjectList projects={this.props.projects} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <CreateProject />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.project);
    return {
        projects: state.project.projects
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchProjects: () => dispatch(getProjectsActionsCreator())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashoard)

[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your reducer, you shouldn't mutate state (See the [Redux docs on immutability](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/prerequisite-concepts)).

```
const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_PROJECT:
            const project = action.project;
            state.projects.unshift(project);
            return {
                ...state
            };
        case GET_PROJECTS:
            state.projects = action.projects;
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

In each of your cases you *are* returning a referentially different copy of state, but you're mutating the original state first. Here's how you want to do it instead:

```
const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_PROJECT:
            return {
                ...state, projects: [action.project, ...state.projects]
            };
        case GET_PROJECTS:
            return {
                ...state, projects: action.projects
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Note that `...state` isn't strictly necessary in this case, since `projects` is your only state (and you want to overwrite it), but if you add more state, you'll need to spread state to avoid overwriting any other state in the store.